# Sublime Text Select and Copy in one (macro and keybinding) not working, why?

Tags: macros, sublimetext3

I have a `select-copy.sublime-macro` files that contains this:

```
[
  { "command": "expand_selection_to_word" },
  { "command": "copy" }
]
```

I then have this in my `sublime-keymap` file:

```
{
      "keys": ["ctrl+d"],
      "command": "run_macro_file",
      "args": {"file": "Packages/User/select-copy.sublime-macro" }
}
```

However, given a line like this:

```
property: val[|]ue;
```

Where `[|]` is the cursor, when I press my keybinding (ctrl+d), I would expect to get 'value' copied. However, when I paste, I actually get the whole line (`property: value`).

Any idea why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because **expand_selection_to_word its not a command** (the right command its expand_selection, and *'words'* should be the value of the *'to'* argument).

So, change your macro to this and it should work:

```
[   
    {
     "command": "expand_selection",
     "args": {"to": "word"}
    },
    {       
        "command": "copy"
    }
]
```

**Note**: the macro was selecting the whole line because its the default behavior of the copy command if nothing its selected (you can try using *ctrl+c* when nothing its selected). In addition, if you open the console and execute the macro you should see a warning message saying *Unknown macro command expand_selection_to_word*.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks. Appreciated the thorough explanation too.